# How to override css property to default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*Updated*

I have set the "height: auto;" property via style on both the fieldset and select elements, however it still results in the select box having the original height specified in the CSS for "fieldset select" which is 20px. If I change that to "auto" in the CSS it works, but as I need to override it, I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

```
                <fieldset style="width:62%; float:left; margin-left: 19%; height: auto; !important">

                    <select style="height: auto; !important" name="searchable[]" id='searchable' multiple='multiple' size='10' >
                        <option value='1'>127.0.0.1</option>
                        <option value='2'>127.0.0.5</option>
                        <option value='3'>127.0.0.10</option>
                        <option value='4'>127.0.0.15</option>
                        <option value='5'>127.0.0.20</option>
                        <option value='6'>127.0.0.25</option>
                        <option value='7'>127.0.0.30</option>
                        <option value='8'>127.0.0.35</option>
                        <option value='9'>127.0.0.40</option>
                        <option value='10'>127.0.0.45</option>
                        <option value='11'>127.0.0.50</option>
                        <option value='12' SELECTED>127.0.0.55</option>
                        <option value='13' SELECTED>127.0.0.60</option>
                    </select>

                </fieldset><div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: the rule `select .clearheight` should be `select.clearheight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
fieldset select.clearheight{
  height: auto;
}
```

You need to chain select and .clearheight

If you need to increase the priority then try this (keep in mind this is bad practice):

```
fieldset select.clearheight{
  height: auto; !important
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this was one of the issues, but even when scrapping the class and just setting it directly in the style property of the element, it isn't working. Is "auto" not the correct option?

Comment: you need to increase the priority if that is the case.  See edit.

Comment: I just added that as well and still not working. I updated the original post as well showing the code

Comment: looking at your code, it looks like the height has been set to auto which is what you are looking for right?

Comment: I gave in and just erased the "height" line in the original css as it doesn't seem to affect the rest of the select boxes but does fix this, maybe its something to do with the script I am using. I will go ahead and accept your answer as it is indeed correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

changes, you have added space between `select .clearheight`

```
                                        /\ 

fieldset select .clearheight{
height: auto;
}
```

to

```
fieldset select.clearheight{
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
<fieldset style="width:62%; float:left; margin-left: 19%;height:auto !important">
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I also tried just setting style="height:auto;" on both the fieldset and the select box and it still didn't work, but when "height:20px" is removed from fieldset css, it still works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 classes and use addClass and removeClass from jquery to toggle them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<select class="clearheight" name="searchable[]" id='searchable' multiple='multiple' size='10' >
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="1">B</option>
    <option value="1">C</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
    fieldset select {
width: 96%;
margin: 0 10px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 20px;
color: #666666;
}

fieldset .clearheight{
height: auto;
}
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/78Fu4/